# Runtime Error Combine Multiple Workbooks into One

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my script to combine multiple workbooks into one but its not working. My range is set to max number of records in one of my files but in reality, I want the code to go into each file, copy every thing from cell A3 to the last column on the right and the last row down, then paste it where the next empty row is in my master file. Right now when I run it, there are huge gaps between data pastes. Also, I dont want any formatting change, I want it to just Paste. Someone please help, below is my code.

```
Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
    "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long

Sub ChDirNet(szPath As String)
    SetCurrentDirectoryA szPath
End Sub

Sub MergeSpecificWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FName As Variant


' Set application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

SaveDriveDir = CurDir
' Change this to the path\folder location of the files.
ChDirNet "F:\Documents\Files\Macro Folder"

FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx*), *.xlsx*", _
                                    MultiSelect:=True)
If IsArray(FName) Then

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1


    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    For FNum = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FName(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

            On Error Resume Next
            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = .Range("A3:CE7771")
            End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else
                ' If the source range uses all columns then
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value
                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next FNum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    ChDirNet SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your data one contiguous block starting at A3, or some other kind of layout?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**Untested**

```
Sub MergeSpecificWorkbooks()

Dim SourceRcount    As Long
Dim rnum            As Long
Dim i               As Long
Dim lastRow         As Long
Dim lastCol         As Long
Dim BaseWks         As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange     As Range
Dim destrange       As Range
Dim myFiles()       As Workbook
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Dim mybook          As Variant

' Set application properties.
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Title = "Select Files to Merge"
    .InitialFileName = "F:\Documents\Files\Macro Folder\"
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files (*.xlsx)", "*.xlsx"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
        ReDim myFiles(1 To .SelectedItems.Count)
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            i = i + 1
            Set myFiles(i) = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
        Next
End With

If Not myFiles(1) Is Nothing Then

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    For Each mybook In myFiles
        With mybook.Sheets(1)
            lastRow = .Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            lastCol = .Rows("3:3").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
            Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
        End With

        SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

        If rnum + SourceRcount <= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
            ' Set the destination range.
            With BaseWks
                Set destrange = .Range(.Cells(rnum, 1), .Cells(rnum + SourceRcount, lastCol))
            End With

            ' Copy the values from the source range to the destination range.
            destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value
            rnum = BaseWks.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        Else
            'MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet.", vbCritical
            'Exit For
            Set BaseWks = BaseWks.Parent.Sheets.Add
            ' Set the destination range in the new sheet.
            With BaseWks
                Set destrange = .Range(.Cells(rnum, 1), .Cells(rnum + SourceRcount, lastCol))
            End With

            ' Copy the values from the source range to the destination range.
            destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value
            rnum = BaseWks.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        End If
    Next mybook
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If

'Close the opened workbooks.
For Each mybook In myFiles
    mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next mybook

' Restore the application properties.
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Note that I set it up so that if the sheet is filled with data, a new sheet is created and the data is pasted to the new sheet. If you don't want that, just comment/delete the code after the `Else` out and uncomment the `Msgbox` and `Exit For`.